# Flutter - How to keep slider label visible?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple slider:

```
Slider(
  inactiveColor: PrimaryColor(),
  activeColor: AccentColor(),
  min: 5,
  max: 20,
  value: myValue,
  onChanged: (newValue){
    setState(() {
     myValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  divisions: 3,
  label: "$myValue",
),
```

When you drag the slider you can see the label, indicating your current value. But when you stop dragging it, the label is no longer visible.

Is there a way how to make the label visible, even when you're not dragging the slider?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the default widget at the moment. You can create a new feature request on Flutter's Github repo.

Comment: It's possible to heavily modify sliders in flutter. I think this article is a good start for you. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do so but you can go with Custom SliderThumbShape which allow you to have a custom paint form there you can add textpainter with the value and draw any custom image below it so you will get the result
I got into this situation before so here is a code sample of what I did

```
class CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  final List<ui.Image> svg;
  CustomThumbShape(this.svg);

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size(50, 50);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
      TextSpan span = TextSpan(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), text:value.toStringAsFixed(1));
      TextPainter tp = TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
      tp.layout();
      context.canvas.drawImage(value == 0 ? svg.last : svg[2], ui.Offset(center.dx - 30, -66), Paint());
      tp.paint(context.canvas, ui.Offset(center.dx - 12, -60));
      context.canvas.drawImage(value == 0 ? svg.first : svg[1], ui.Offset(center.dx - 12, -27), Paint());
  }
}
```

Then you can wrap your slider with SliderTheme and adding the thumbShape with your custom one it will look like this

```
SliderTheme(
data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
thumbShape: CustomThumbShape()),
child: Slider(
inactiveColor: PrimaryColor(),
active color: AccentColor(),
min: 5,
max: 20,
value: myValue,
onChanged: (newValue) {  setState(() { myValue = newValue;});},
divisions: 3,
label: "$myValue",
),)
```

this is actual result

[image: Result]

Comment: Where is the `this.svg` ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan 

'this.svg' is an attribute passed in the constructor the value is a result of decoding a SVG string into an Image object 

using load picture function : 
var picture = await vg.vg.loadPicture(const SvgStringLoader(rawSvg),null)
ui.Image = picture.toImage(21, 63);

dont forget to import the flutter_svg as vg or any thing u need 
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart' as vg;

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way of forcing the display of the label, however, you can custom one using Painter. I created my own following another dev's code in the flutter issue.
Check the link -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34704

I hope this helps.

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
                        showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.never,
                        valueIndicatorColor: Colors.black,
                        valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        thumbShape: ThumbShape(),
                      ),
                      child: Slider( ... ))


class ThumbShape extends RoundSliderThumbShape {
  final _indicatorShape = const PaddleSliderValueIndicatorShape();

  const ThumbShape();

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    super.paint(
      context,
      center,
      activationAnimation: activationAnimation,
      enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      value: value,
      textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
      sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
      labelPainter: labelPainter,
      parentBox: parentBox,
      textDirection: textDirection,
    );
    _indicatorShape.paint(
      context,
      center,
      activationAnimation: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1),
      enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
      labelPainter: labelPainter,
      parentBox: parentBox,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      value: value,
      textScaleFactor: 0.7,
      sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
      textDirection: textDirection,
    );
  }
}
```